# As an Independent Contractor, do I need to collect tax on the first $30,000?

Tags: taxes, canada

In Canada, you need to collect tax if you make MORE than $30,000 in a year.  However, what about the first $30,000 while you are under?  I already have a tax number, and I will be starting my first contract soon (before this, I was a normal employee), I am wondering if I need to be collecting tax too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did extensive research and here is the answer:

```
You do need to collect tax as long as you have an Activated Tax Number.
```

What I ended up doing is to Deactivate my Tax Number, which you can do over the phone so it's quite easy.  This allow me $30,000 of HST/GST free income, which at that point, THEN I will reactivate my Tax Number and start collecting tax again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your HST/GST number, then you are required to collect tax as per normal. The issue comes in if you are making more than $30,000 per quarter, as you must then register and collect on future transactions [[Source - CRA Mandatory Registration](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/rgstrng/mndtry-eng.html)]. I would double-check with an accountant though as per the possible penalty if you aren't charging taxes yet, but it doesn't sound like it's a concern. Do remember though, that you are allowed to push invoicing to the next year, if it helps you out to stay under the $30,000. As per the [CRA's page on voluntarily registering](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/rgstrng/vlntry-eng.html), once you're registered, you MUST charge, unless you have [exempt items](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/gnrl/txbl/menu-eng.html); check this list of [taxable items](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/gnrl/txbl/txblxmpt-eng.html) as well.

See [CRA - How to charge GST/HST](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/gnrl/stps/cllct-eng.html) and [CRA - Calculating how much GST/HST to send in](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/gnrl/stps/wrkng-eng.html)

Comment: What about income filed under T4A?

Comment: I'll have to check tomorrow at a computer

Comment: @YongkeBillYu I would check [this page](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/pyrll/rtrns/t4a/xcptns-eng.html) on the CRA's website. I don't know the answer to your question though